# can't install numpy package in pycharm with latest pycharm and python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, installation, pycharm

I installed Python 2.7, Pycharm 2017.3 and in pycharm in

```
settings > project interpreter > add package
```

I searched for numpy and installed the package but I get this error:

[image: error]

```
Error occured:
    _configtest.c(7): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'volatile'

Proposed solution:
  Try to run this command from the system terminal. 
  Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at
  'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\second\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.
```

I tried by reinstalling everything but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Hadvani,  what happened when you ran the command?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are trying to install numpy on windows. 
On windows, install this package could be quite complicated, so my suggestion is to use an unofficial installer for Numpy.

[Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) you can find the link with all unofficial installers, please search and open the Numpy link in the list.

Keep in mind to choose the right version, in this way:

1. cp = python version (i.e. cp27 = Pythonv2.7)
2. win_amd64 = x86_64 or win32 = windows 32 bit

Download it and then install it with the following command

```
pip install --user <numpy.whl>
```

for example, the following command install numpy v.1.13.3, for Python2.7 and for windowns 32:

```
pip install --user numpy‑1.13.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved on Pycharm Pro and Comunity Edition

This is about near deprecation python 2.7, and dependencies requires older versions.

***File > Settings > project interpreter > Double Click to pip package > 
Check Specify version to 9.0.1 (downgrade version to older). Click to install package.

***File > Settings > project interpreter > Add  package (+) > Search and select matplotlib > Check Specify version to 1.5.3 (Downgrade to older). Click install package.

Regards. ;-)